# Why is my insertRow method adding blank cells to my table?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add the results from a fetch request into a new row in a table. However, When I run the function to do that, the first click adds a blank row instead of adding my desired data. Additionally, the data that I would have liked to add gets added the next time the function is ran. I have no idea what is wrong and I have tried so many things. I believe this problem is causing my other function called "total()" to return an error as the first cell is undefined instead of containing a value.

Here is my javascript:

```
document.getElementById('getFood').addEventListener('click', getFood);
document.getElementById('getFood').addEventListener('click', total);
/*function getText() {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url:
      'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/nutrition?query=' +
      document.getElementById('foodInput'),
    headers: { 'X-Api-Key': 'vrtwcc/pVgAr2o/a4dEyYA==hR1m7lLVdU4ho4hW' },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
      console.log(result);
    },
    error: function ajaxError(jqXHR) {
      console.error('Error: ', jqXHR.responseText);
    },
  });
}*/
/*function getFood(foodName) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(
    'get',
    'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/nutrition?query=' + foodName,
    true
  );

  xhr.send();
  xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  });
}
getFood('fries');*/
function getFood() {
  fetch(
    'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/nutrition?query=' +
      `${document.getElementById('foodInput').value}`,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'X-Api-Key': 'vrtwcc/pVgAr2o/a4dEyYA==hR1m7lLVdU4ho4hW' },
      contentType: 'application/json',
    }
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      foodQuery = data[0].name;
      calorieQuery = `${data[0].calories} calories`;
    });
  let table = document
    .getElementById('foodTable')
    .getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  let row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = foodQuery;
  cell2.innerHTML = calorieQuery;

  // row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = foodQuery;
  // row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = calorieQuery;
  //document.getElementById('foodInput').value = '';
}
function total() {
  let table = document.getElementById('foodTable');
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    total += Number(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerText);
  }
  document.getElementById('tableTotal').value = total;
}
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"
      integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid border border-primary">
      <strong>Jason's Calorie Counter </strong><br />
      <form>
        <div class="form-group" id="">
          <label>Food Selection</label>
          <input
            class="form-control"
            id="foodInput"
            placeholder="Enter food here"
          />
          <small id="foodHelp" class="form-text text-muted"
            >Nutrition data for each food item is scaled to 100g unless a
            quantity is specified
          </small>
          <br />
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="getFood">
            Get Food
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="foodTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Food</th>
          <th scope="col">Calories</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="rows1">
          <td colspan="2" id="tableTotal">Total</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

One more important detail: The new row gets added correctly when just adding a string, so it may have to do with the variable or the fetch request. Thank you very much for your time and if there is more information that is missing, please tell me and I will do my best to add it.

I have tried changing the type of data being added, adding them to different parts of the table, changing syntax, etc..

Answer (score 2):

`total()` is probably called before the number is populated.  You should have it execute after the cell is populated and not on click.